# Can't find local placeholder mapping for parameter named 'x', al obtener el resultado de un CallableStatement

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedure, jdbc

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado, `procNumEmpleadosSalarioIntervalo`, que devuelve la cantidad de empleados en un determinado rango salarial.

Este procedimiento necesita de dos argumentos, el valor mínimo y el valor máximo. El procedimiento almacenado funciona correctamente.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procNumEmpleadosSalarioIntervalo`(in i int, in j int, out x int)
BEGIN
    select
        count(*)
    from
        empleados
    where
        salario between i and j into x;
END
```

Ejecutándolo en MySQL Workbench.

```
Call procNumEmpleadosSalarioIntervalo(1500, 1900, @result);
select @result;
```

> Devuelve 5

Esto mismo tengo que implementarlo en Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    
    try {
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call procNumEmpleadosSalarioIntervalo(?, ?)}");
        cStmt.setInt(1, 1500);
        cStmt.setInt(2, 1900);
        cStmt.registerOutParameter("x", Types.INTEGER);
        cStmt.execute();
        rs = cStmt.getResultSet();
        
        int x = cStmt.getInt("x");
        System.out.println(x);
        
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
               
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("SQL Exception: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Y el error que recibo precisamente en el argumento de salida:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can't find local placeholder mapping for parameter named 'x'.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Nunca he usado esto así que lo que te voy a decir tal vez sea una tontería, pero cuando lo llamas desde el workbench y te funciona le pasas tres parámetros: `procNumEmpleadosSalarioIntervalo(1500, 1900, @result);`, y cuando lo llamas desde java solo dos: `conn.prepareCall("{call procNumEmpleadosSalarioIntervalo(?, ?)}")`, tal vez deberías usar un parámetro con nombre ahí? O al menos un tercer parámetro?

Comment: @Benito-B no ibas mal desencaminado, tenía que añadir el argumento de salida con otro `?` y además, luego no estaba configurando bien `registerOutParameter`. Añadiré mi solución por si a alguien le pueda venir bien. ¡Gracias!

Comment: No hay de qué. Añade la solución y luego podrás marcarla como aceptada, así nos aseguramos de que otras personas con el mismo error puedan encontrarla facilmente! Un saludo

Comment: Por lo que recuerdo, en tu llamada necesitas poner '?' para todo, inclusive para salidas, en su caso solo puedo ver dos '?' donde debería tener 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a mi problema es que faltaba un ? en el método `prepareCall`, precisamente el de salida del procedimiento almacenado en `MySQL Workbench`.

```
CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call procNumEmpleadosComisionIntervalo(?, ?, ?)}");
```

Además de lo anterior, también estaba usando incorrectamente el método `registerOutParameter`, puesto que este necesita la posición del dato.

```
cStmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
```

Una vez hecho esto y ejecutado la sentencia bastaría con recoger lo que devuelve la consulta en una variable, indicando qué posición es la que queremos (en mi caso la última, la 3).

```
int x = cStmt.getInt(3);
```

El código completo en el `try-catch` sería el siguiente:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call procNumEmpleadosComisionIntervalo(?, ?, ?)}");
cStmt.setInt(1, MIN);
cStmt.setInt(2, MAX);
cStmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
cStmt.execute();
        
int x = cStmt.getInt(3);
        
System.out.println("El número de empleados entre " + MIN + " y " + MAX + " es: " + x);
```